# Combating class imbalance with the right loss function: IoU, Dice or 2-class Dice?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function, imbalanced-data

I am currently working on my Bachelor's thesis and facing some difficulties while trying to understand differences in loss functions regarding class imbalance, and class imbalance itself.

I am working on a Segmentation Problem with a variation of the U-Net (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf).

My dataset contains 11 classes, wherein one is far less frequent than most others. The input to my network is a np-array of shape (700,512,512,3) for the input rgb-images, and shape (700,512,512,11) for the ground truth labels. Each of the 11 channels of the ground truth are binary encoded (1 for specific class present, 0 for lack thereof). So there is one mask per class per image. In most masks, the amount of 1s are far less than those of 0s.

First regarding the class imbalance:

I have not found any clear definition of the termn "class imbalance". In my opinion, three interpretations are possible:

1. Over all 700 input images, one class is far less frequent than most others.
2. Within one mask of one image, the number of 0s is far higher than that of the 1s
3. Over all input images, for one class, the (mean) number of 0s is far higher than that of the 1s

For each of those interpretations, I can imagine problems. Which one is commonly meant when talking about class imbalance?
And how would that one lead to problems?

Now the loss functions. The loss functions I am trying to understand are:

- IoU approximation Loss (http://www.cs.umanitoba.ca/~ywang/papers/isvc16.pdf)
- Dice Loss (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.00478.pdf)
- 2-class Dice Loss (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.03237.pdf)

In my research I have read that IoU Loss has problems when facing imbalanced datasets. I have also read that Dice Loss performes better in that case, but I could not find an explanation. It was just discounted as "common knowledge". I assume 2-class Dice loss would be even better, since it regards the binary problem from both perspectives, compensating the class imbalance somewhat.

My assumption based mainly on an example I exercised (see below) is:

With IoU, false positive predictions have a smaller error compared to that for false negatives. However, the probability of receiving a false positive prediction are higher for a category with few pixels, so that the network might settle for false negatives. The Dice Loss punishes false negatives and false positives less than the IoU Loss and the difference between false positive error and false negative error is smaller for the Dice loss. This should lead to improved performance, because the imbalance in probabilities is compensated slightly. With the 2-class Dice Loss, all errors are punished from both perspectives, resulting in less difference between false negative and false positive error terms.

Is any of this true? Where am I wrong? At this point, I am really confused and would appreciate any indication. Some sources regarding my questions would also help a lot.

And the last question: What loss function would be most suitable to my case with regard to class imbalance?

Thanks in advance!

```
Example with 9 pixels, two 1s, seven 0s:

         all correct | 1 false positive | 1 false negative

IoU     |     1      |        0.33      |      0.5

Dice    |     1      |        0.2       |      0.33

Dice2   |     1      |        0.14      |      0.2
```

Comment: regarding loss function, take a look at this discussion here, for multi class image segmentation dice loss for unet. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9395.